# changing the screen resolution on ipad programmatically

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, screen, resolution

I'd like to know how change the screen resolution on the ipad3 since it is twice the size as needed in the game that I'm creating. I know that I can't set [UIScreen mainscreen] directly. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? Why not make full use of all the pixels that are available?

I can guarantee that New iPad owners will hate your game and trash it in reviews if you deliberately lower the resolution. Even if you're doing a pixel-art game, you can still use the extra real pixels to better align your stylistic pixels, and to render far-off objects with full detail (by not scaling them at all).

If you still really want to make your app look ugly, there are two things you might try. One would be to set the screen's current mode (you'll have to see what modes are available, and I don't hold hope that that array holds more than one object); the other would be to set your window's content scale factor.

Comment: Simple reason, the game is already published and a quick fix needs to get out to the market fast.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem, but I did it by merely having a fixed scale on the game instead of having it get from the device.

Comment: @user1036272: If you want to find out the correct scale factor to use, ask the window or the screen for its `contentScaleFactor`.